# Pine Script - If statement with a plot

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I am new to Pine Script but hoping to get some assistance with two `if` statements and based on the outcome I need to plot a flat line for the week (Monday to Friday), the following week the Marker (see below) should re-calculate.

```
pLevel = (prevHighHTF + prevLowHTF + prevCloseHTF) / 3
r1Level = (pLevel - prevLowHTF) + pLevel
s1Level = pLevel - (prevHighHTF - pLevel)


//Marker Calculations
// Close above Pro_High on Friday
if prevCloseHTF[1] > r1Level[1]
    Marker = r1Level - ((r1Level - prevCloseHTF) * 0.55)

//Close Below Pro_Low on Friday
if prevCloseHTF[1] < s1Level
    Marker = ((prevCloseHTF - s1Level) * .55) + s1Level
```

Using this code, How can I plot the Marker on Monday as a single line and recalculated the following week?

Comment: Please update the tags on your Question to reflect the language.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable in the global scope first and then re-assign the value using the `:=` operator.
Here is the example:

```
var float Marker = na

//Marker Calculations
// Close above Pro_High on Friday
if prevCloseHTF[1] > r1Level[1]
    Marker := r1Level - ((r1Level - prevCloseHTF) * 0.55)

//Close Below Pro_Low on Friday
if prevCloseHTF[1] < s1Level
    Marker := ((prevCloseHTF - s1Level) * .55) + s1Level
```

Comment: Many thanks, e2e4!   I will give this a try and see how it works.  Your kind assistance is appreciated.